# Изменить автора приложения в Play Marker

Tags: android, google-play, playmarket

Публиковал приложение от имени заказчика. Автором приложения в Play Market указан профиль клиента. Он попросил сменить автора. Указать, например, ArtCompany.

Это можно сделать?

Comment: Одного приложения нельзя. Только всего аккаунта.

Comment: а как изменить весь аккаунт?

Comment: Пойти в настройки и вместо Иван Петров написать ArtCompany.

Answer (score 0):

[Преходим в консоль](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/#AppTransferPlace) и заполняем заявку на перенос приложения на аккаунт заказчика

Comment: Почему не является? Нельзя изменить название автора, можно создать аккаунт новый  с другим именем и переносить или на существующий переносить.